# Proper installation of x64 minispy minifilter driver

Tags: drivers

I'm trying to get the minispy minifilter from Microsoft to install and function properly. I started a new empty kernel driver project in VS2013, and compiled the driver and test signed it.

I can use the wdreg.exe utility to successfully install the driver, and I put a DbgPrint test in the beginning of the DriverEntry() function and I can read it using DbgView so the driver appears to install ok. Also using wdreg.exe to install the driver creates a Wdf01000 named service and using sc query Wdf01000 I can view it running. Using fltmc.exe to load or view the instances gives odd results.

Microsoft says that to install it I should right click the .inf file and click install, and when I do this Windows tells me "The .inf file you have selected does not support this method of installation". Pasted is a copy of my .inf file generated by VS2013.

Can someone tell me the correct way to install the minispy driver, start the minispy driver and attach it to a filesystem on x64 Win7/Win8? Thanks

```
[Version]
Signature="$WINDOWS NT$"
Class=Sample ; TODO: edit Class
ClassGuid={78A1C341-4539-11d3-B88D-00C04FAD5171} ; TODO: edit ClassGuid
Provider=%ManufacturerName%
CatalogFile=MiniSpyDev.cat  
DriverVer= ; TODO: set DriverVer in stampinf property pages

[DestinationDirs]
DefaultDestDir = 12

; ================= Class section =====================

[ClassInstall32]
Addreg=SampleClassReg

[SampleClassReg]
HKR,,,0,%ClassName%
HKR,,Icon,,-5

[SourceDisksNames]
1 = %DiskName%,,,""

[SourceDisksFiles]
MiniSpyDev.sys  = 1,,

;*****************************************
; Install Section
;*****************************************

[Manufacturer]
%ManufacturerName%=Standard,NT$ARCH$

[Standard.NT$ARCH$]
%MiniSpyDev.DeviceDesc%=MiniSpyDev_Device, Root\MiniSpyDev ; TODO: edit hw-id

[MiniSpyDev_Device.NT]
CopyFiles=Drivers_Dir

[Drivers_Dir]
MiniSpyDev.sys

;-------------- Service installation
[MiniSpyDev_Device.NT.Services]
AddService = MiniSpyDev,%SPSVCINST_ASSOCSERVICE%, MiniSpyDev_Service_Inst

; -------------- MiniSpyDev driver install sections
[MiniSpyDev_Service_Inst]
DisplayName    = %MiniSpyDev.SVCDESC%
ServiceType    = 2               ; SERVICE_KERNEL_DRIVER
StartType      = 0               ; 
ErrorControl   = 1               ; SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL
ServiceBinary  = %12%\MiniSpyDev.sys
LoadOrderGroup = Extended Base

;
;--- MiniSpyDev_Device Coinstaller installation ------
;

[DestinationDirs]
MiniSpyDev_Device_CoInstaller_CopyFiles = 11

[MiniSpyDev_Device.NT.CoInstallers]
AddReg=MiniSpyDev_Device_CoInstaller_AddReg 
CopyFiles=MiniSpyDev_Device_CoInstaller_CopyFiles

[MiniSpyDev_Device_CoInstaller_AddReg]
HKR,,CoInstallers32,0x00010000,     "WdfCoInstaller$KMDFCOINSTALLERVERSION$.dll,WdfCoInstaller"

[MiniSpyDev_Device_CoInstaller_CopyFiles]
WdfCoInstaller$KMDFCOINSTALLERVERSION$.dll

[SourceDisksFiles]
WdfCoInstaller$KMDFCOINSTALLERVERSION$.dll=1 ; make sure the number matches with               SourceDisksNames

[MiniSpyDev_Device.NT.Wdf]
KmdfService =  MiniSpyDev, MiniSpyDev_wdfsect
[MiniSpyDev_wdfsect]
KmdfLibraryVersion = $KMDFVERSION$

[Strings]
SPSVCINST_ASSOCSERVICE= 0x00000002
ManufacturerName="" ; TODO: add ManufacturerName
ClassName="Samples" ; TODO: edit ClassName
DiskName = "MiniSpyDev Installation Disk"
MiniSpyDev.DeviceDesc = "MiniSpyDev Device"
MiniSpyDev.SVCDESC = "MiniSpyDev Service"
```

Comment: You might want to flag this and ask a mod to migrate it to [su] for you. SO is geared toward questions about code.

Comment: Thanks for trying Caleb, but that doesn't help and there's a lot of code involved in this question.

Comment: Here's another similar (but different) question the mods felt appropriate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19779530/installing-file-system-minifilter-from-inf-launched-from-debug?rq=1. You should let the mods make that decision in the future and try to only post in topics you know about....

Comment: I see that you're new here, so you may not realize that it's the StackOverflow community, not moderators, that makes most decisions about what is/isn't on topic. To me, your question appears to be off topic because it relates to installing an existing piece of software and it isn't about a problem with code that you're writing; also, the "code" you included appears to be a configuration file. I certainly didn't mean to offend you by suggesting that you have your question moved -- I was only trying to help you find a place for it where the community wouldn't end up voting to close. Good luck.

Comment: The community isn't voting to close it here either, and once again that's for the community to decide and not u. This definitely has a lot to do with code and most likely requires a programmer to answer it. There were many changes that needed to be made to the .inf file to get it to work with the minifilter code, that's the short version of the answer, but thank u for the input.

Comment: @Caleb well, it's been three years, but user3375969 is right. This is a question for SO, not SU. Unfortunately SO isn't very accepting of fringe developer issues like this one, exactly because of the community decision making process you pointed out. And kernel mode drivers on Windows are a fringe topic on SO. No one would have the off idea to migrate a topic about tools inherently only used by developers for other domains. (Make, CMake, Nant, Ninja, Visual Studio ...) just because they're not directly related to *code*.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a .cat file based on the inf and then sign the .cat.  There is a tool called inf2cat that creates the cat then just use signtool to sign it.  Once done, it should install no problem.

Answer (score 0):

So you have your driver running, great. The [Minispy FSFD sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/filesys/miniFilter/minispy) is comprised of two parts, though.

But let's backtrack a little. Theat INF does not contain a `DefaultInstall` or `DefaultInstall.Services` section - a prerequisite to using the method you attempted (Right-click + "Install").

You can see what command gets executed by looking at `HKCR\inffile\shell\Install\command` (`%SystemRoot%\System32\InfDefaultInstall.exe "%1"` in my case). This, effectively uses `setupapi.dll` (`InstallHinfSection`) to attempt the installation. The same can be achieved using `rundll32.exe` according [to this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/using-an-inf-file-to-install-a-file-system-filter-driver).

Guessing by where the sample comes from (the WDK), I'd probably attempt installing via `dpinst.exe` which comes inside the `redist\DIFx\dpinst` folder of the Windows 7 SP1 WDK, for example. But since you already managed to install the driver, this doesn't seem to be the issue. The driver is evidently running.

Anyway, you need to understand that just because you see debug output from `DriverEntry()` doesn't mean that the filter driver is attached to any volumes. In fact the documentation for Minispy explicitly states that you need a user mode utility (doesn't state anything about a Windows service, though). And when I look at the sample code I would expect to get the mini-FSFD named `minispy.sys` and a console application named `minispy.exe` from a build. The latter is supposed to control the former, including control of attaching to volumes (consult `InterpretCommand()` inside `mspyUser.c` for details). For example the command `a` for attach, `d` for detach and `l` for listing devices (volumes).

---

I don't know why you used `wdreg.exe`, but the result looks as if it installed some user-mode driver (WDF/WUDF)?! This is a kernel mode driver, though, so it's natural for this not to work.